I’ve already called her four times ________. Why not before?
I’ve already called her four times ________.

 today
 again
 before
 yesterday

Why is the answer today not before?

Because yesterday, before and again would take a simple past.


I've already called her four times today.

No issues there.

I've already called her four times yesterday.

yesterday confines the action to the past so simple past is the better choice and the present perfect is marginal at best.  I already called her four times yesterday.

I've already called her four times again.

That only makes sense in a context like the following, where the speaker is throwing the word "again" back at the other person.

I can't get ahold of her.
-- Well, call her again.
I've already called her four times "again".

And the next:

I've already called her four times before.

already and before in the same clause are somewhat at odds with each other, especially in combination with "four times".  So it's not clear what that is intended to mean, as it's not quite idiomatic:
I've called her four times already, trying to reach her?
I've called her four times in the past on four separate occasions?
P.S. It's a more fruitful exercise, I think, to ask how to say something in a real-world context, than to provide sentences, without context, and ask what is wrong with them.

I've already called her four times yesterday sounds as though you are being asked to call her yesterday for a fifth time. Without a time machine this doesn't work.

Already carries the implication before now, so adding 'before'  is superfluous.
